# How can I walk this type with a recursion scheme instead of explicit recursion?

Tags: haskell, recursive-datastructures, recursion-schemes

Consider this code:

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

data MyStructure = Foo Int | Bar String MyStructure | Baz MyStructure MyStructure | Qux Bool Bool MyStructure MyStructure deriving(Eq,Show)

makeReplacements :: [(MyStructure, MyStructure)] -> MyStructure -> MyStructure
makeReplacements replacements structure = fromMaybe (descend structure) (lookup structure replacements)
  where
    descend :: MyStructure -> MyStructure
    descend (Foo x) = Foo x
    descend (Bar x y) = Bar x (makeReplacements replacements y)
    descend (Baz x y) = Baz (makeReplacements replacements x) (makeReplacements replacements y)
    descend (Qux x y z w) = Qux x y (makeReplacements replacements z) (makeReplacements replacements w)
```

It defines a recursive data type, and a function that performs a search-and-replace by walking it. However, I'm using explicit recursion and would like to use a recursion scheme instead.

First, I threw in `makeBaseFunctor ''MyStructure`. For clarity, I expanded the resulting Template Haskell and the derived Functor instance below. I was then able to rewrite `descend`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Data.Functor.Foldable (Base, Recursive(..), Corecursive(..))

data MyStructure = Foo Int | Bar String MyStructure | Baz MyStructure MyStructure | Qux Bool Bool MyStructure MyStructure deriving(Eq,Show)

makeReplacements :: [(MyStructure, MyStructure)] -> MyStructure -> MyStructure
makeReplacements replacements structure = fromMaybe (descend structure) (lookup structure replacements)
  where
    descend :: MyStructure -> MyStructure
    descend = embed . fmap (makeReplacements replacements) . project

-- begin code that would normally be auto-generated
data MyStructureF r = FooF Int | BarF String r | BazF r r | QuxF Bool Bool r r deriving(Foldable,Traversable)

instance Functor MyStructureF where
  fmap _ (FooF x) = FooF x
  fmap f (BarF x y) = BarF x (f y)
  fmap f (BazF x y) = BazF (f x) (f y)
  fmap f (QuxF x y z w) = QuxF x y (f z) (f w)

type instance Base MyStructure = MyStructureF

instance Recursive MyStructure where
  project (Foo x) = FooF x
  project (Bar x y) = BarF x y
  project (Baz x y) = BazF x y
  project (Qux x y z w) = QuxF x y z w

instance Corecursive MyStructure where
  embed (FooF x) = Foo x
  embed (BarF x y) = Bar x y
  embed (BazF x y) = Baz x y
  embed (QuxF x y z w) = Qux x y z w
-- end code that would normally be auto-generated
```

If I were to stop here, I'd already have a win: I no longer have to write out all of the cases in `descend`, and I can't accidentally make a mistake like `descend (Baz x y) = Baz x (makeReplacements replacements y)` (forgetting to replace inside `x`). However, there's still explicit recursion here, since I'm still using `makeReplacements` from inside its own definition. How can I rewrite this to remove that, so that I'm doing all of my recursion inside of the recursion schemes?

Comment: I'm not sure I've followed your code correctly, but `descend` looks like a paramorphism to me. You want to look at the to-be-folded node first, to see if it should be replaced, and if not then you look at the already-recursively-folded result that a catamorphism would give you. Does the signature of [para](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.1.3/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:para), specialized to your types, look promising?

Comment: @amalloy `para` is `(Base t (t, a) -> a) -> t -> a`. To me, this looks close but not quite perfect. Wouldn't I actually want `((t, Base t a) -> a) -> t -> a` or `((t, Base t (t, a)) -> a) -> t -> a` so that I can look at the element I'm on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution that I'm reasonably happy with: an apomorphism.

```
makeReplacements replacements = apo coalg
  where
    coalg :: MyStructure -> MyStructureF (Either MyStructure MyStructure)
    coalg structure = case lookup structure replacements of
      Just replacement -> Left <$> project replacement
      Nothing -> Right <$> project structure
```

Having thought about this a little more, I also saw a symmetry in this that leads to an equivalent paramorphism:

```
makeReplacements replacements = para alg
  where
    alg :: MyStructureF (MyStructure, MyStructure) -> MyStructure
    alg structure = case lookup (embed $ fst <$> structure) replacements of
      Just replacement -> replacement
      Nothing -> embed $ snd <$> structure
```

Comment: `apo` looks more apropos to me. In one sense my suggestion of `para`, the dual of `apo`, was very close; in another I was the wrongest it is possible to be!

Answer (score 3):

Following up from the discussion under your question

> `para` is `(Base t (t, a) -> a) -> t -> a`. To me, this looks close but not quite perfect. Wouldn't I actually want `((t, Base t a) -> a) -> t -> a` or `((t, Base t (t, a)) -> a) -> t -> a` so that I can look at the element I'm on?

That's still a paramorphism. The type of `para` looks weird but it is the more precise one. A pair `(t, Base t a)` does not encode the invariant that both components are always going to have the "same" constructor.

What you propose still seems like the most natural way of defining `makeReplacements`, it's just not defined in the recursion-schemes library.

```
para' :: Recursive t => (t -> Base t a -> a) -> t -> a
para' alg = go where
  go x = alg x (fmap go (project x))
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be more enlightening to implement `para'` in terms of `para`, using `fmap fst` and `fmap snd`?

Comment: @HTNW Is that even possible without adding a `Corecursive` constraint? Without that, it looks like you can get a `Base t t` but not the `t` you need.